# Count for all values of enum in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, enums, group-by, count

I have a table called `users`, which has the following columns:

```
id: INT NOT NULL
face: face_type
```

`face_type` is an ENUM type that has the following values: `'square'`, `'round'` and `'triangle'`.

And I have another table called `houses`, which has the following columns:

```
id: INT NOT NULL
user_id: INT NOT NULL
```

Now, I want to get all the houses grouped by the different type of face types. So, what I have so far is this:

```
SELECT users.face_type, COUNT(*)
FROM users
LEFT JOIN houses ON houses.user_id = users.id
GROUP BY users.face_type
```

The problem is that I also want to get rows for `face_type` which none of the users have, as well as a result for NULL face_type. So, for example, if I have the following data:

```
users (id, face_type)

1, 'round'
2, 'triangle'

houses (id, user_id)
1, 1
2, 1
3, 2
```

I would expect the result to be:

```
face_type, count
'round'          2
'triangle'       1
'square'         0
null             0
```

I know how to get all the potential values of the `face_type` ENUM, by doing  :

```
SELECT unnest(enum_range(NULL::face_type)) AS face_types;
```

But I don't know how to use that to count all potential face types in the aggregate, as well as also calculating for NULL face types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT ft.face_type, COUNT(h.user_id)
FROM (SELECT unnest(enum_range(NULL::face_type)) AS face_types
     ) ft LEFT JOIN
     users u
     ON u.face_type = ft.face_type LEFT JOIN
     houses h
     ON h.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY ft.face_type;
```

To get `NULL`, just use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT ft.face_type, COUNT(h.user_id)
FROM (SELECT unnest(enum_range(NULL::face_type)) AS face_types
      UNION ALL
      SELECT NULL
     ) ft LEFT JOIN
     users u
     ON u.face_type = ft.face_type LEFT JOIN
     houses h
     ON h.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY ft.face_type;
```

Of course, the `=` will not every match.  If that is possible, then you want to change the `JOIN` condition to `u.face_type is not distinct from ft.face_type`.

Comment: That would not include a row for 'null' face_type tho. As in, NULL is not part of the ENUM, but I want to have a row that counts for users who don't have face_type (and if all users have a face_type I still want the NULL row to be there, stating that users with no face_type have no houses).

Comment: Is there a way to prepend/append NULL into `enum_range(NULL::face_type)`?

Comment: What does it mean 'the = will not every match'?

Comment: This is not working as expected. It is not counting the users where face_type is NULL.

Answer (score 1):

to COUNT(houses.*)

```
SELECT face_type.type, COUNT(houses.*)
FROM (SELECT unnest(enum_range(NULL::face_type))) AS face_type(type)
FULL JOIN users ON users.face_type=face_type.type
LEFT JOIN houses ON houses.user_id = users.id
GROUP BY face_type.type
```

Comment: Why the COALESCE?

Answer (score 0):

A `LEFT JOIN` starting from the `ENUM` and going to `users` and `houses` will allow you to recover totals for each enumerated value. To also display the `NULL` face types, you can use a `UNION` query.

```
SELECT 
    ft.face_type,
    COUNT(ho.user_id) as cnt
FROM 
    (SELECT unnest(enum_range(NULL::face_type)) AS face_types) ft
    LEFT JOIN users us ON us.face_type = ft.fact_type
    LEFT JOIN houses ho ON ho.user_id = us.id
GROUP BY ft.face_type
UNION
SELECT
    null,
    COUNT(ho.user_id)
FROM houses ho
INNER JOIN users us ON ho.user_id = us.id AND us.face_type IS NULL
ORDER BY cnt desc
```